# Broadcast Receivers in Xamarin.Android (2021 Year)

Tags: xamarin.android

My goal after restarting the phone is to restore scheduled local notifications. (To restore local notifications I need to take local notifications from the local database.)

I manage to send a message to the user's screen using a code

```
Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "1:"+intent.Action, ToastLength.Long).Show();

Intent message = new Intent("com.xamarin.example.TEST");
message.PutExtra("key", "value");
Android.Support.V4.Content.LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(message);
```

But my goal is to get data from the database and restore scheduled local notifications. I'm trying to do this with the following code.
This code doesn't work. There are no mistakes. Just the script is not executed.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "Reboot complete receiver")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, typeof(BootRestoreAlarm));
context.StartService(intent1);
}
}
```

```
//BootRestoreAlarm Class
 public class BootRestoreAlarm
{
public async Task BootRestoreAlarmTask()
{

try
{
var i = 0;
while (i < 3)
{
// Get notice
var item = await App.Database.GetItemAsyncNotice(DateTime.Now);
if (item.Text != null && item.Id.ToString() != null && item.Description != null)
{
//Recreate alarms
AppShell appshell = new AppShell();
await Task.Run(() => appshell.OnSendClick(item.Text, item.Description, item.Id.ToString(), item.DataTime));
//END Recreate alarms
}
i++;
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to show a notification when the device started.

BroadcastReceiver.cs

```
 [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
public class MyBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, typeof(MyService));
        intent1.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        //Use the StartForegroundService because Android 8.0 and heigher doesn't support to start a background service when the device is on boot.
        context.StartForegroundService(intent1);
    }
}
```

MyService.cs

```
 [Service]
public class MyService : Service
{
    // A notification requires an id that is unique to the application.
    public const string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000";
    private readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
    private readonly string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "hello";
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
               NotificationImportance.Low);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.III)
            .SetContentTitle("Hello")
            .SetContentText("A Notificatioin");
        notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }
}
```